# Access query based on filtered subform only returns first subform record

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form with unbound comboboxes that are used to filter a subform based on the combobox value selected by the user. The subform is based on a query that pulls data from the source table. The subform can be filtered on fields in the query. The subform filters the way I want it to when the comboboxes are used. The issue is I want to have a command button that opens a report that displays the currently displayed results of the filtered subform.

I have a report that uses a separate query as the record source. The query criteria for the record ID is set to the record ID field in the subform. The problem I am having is that the query that serves as the record source for the report will only return the first value from the subform.

The SQL statement is below. I have tried removing the WHERE clause and using different join types. If I remove the WHERE clause the query will return all of the records from the source tables regardless of join type. If I add the WHERE clause it only returns the first record in the subform regardless of join type.

```
SELECT SubrecipientIDSheet.ID, SubrecipientIDSheet.AgencyID, AgencyIDSheet.SubgranteeLegalName, SubrecipientIDSheet.IsAmendment, SubrecipientIDSheet.RecordDate, SubrecipientIDSheet.HasSubrecipient, SubrecipientIDSheet.IsActiveSub, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrecipientName, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepAddress, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepEHA, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepEHAVet, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepERA, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepESG, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepHSP, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepHTBA, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepLIHRF, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepSHAP, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepCounty1, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepCounty2, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepCounty3, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepAuthorizedRepresentative, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepRepTitle, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepEmail, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepPhone, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepTargetPop1, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepTargetPop2, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepTargetPop3, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepTargetPop4, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepOtherTargetPop, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepPrimaryService, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepCulturalSpecificPop, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepUseHMIS, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepHMISSupportPlan, SubrecipientIDSheet.SubrepDataReportMethod, SubrecipientIDSheet.DescripCurrentScope, SubrecipientIDSheet.DescripChangeScop, SubrecipientIDSheet.DescripWhyChange
FROM AgencyIDSheet INNER JOIN SubrecipientIDSheet ON AgencyIDSheet.ID = SubrecipientIDSheet.AgencyID
WHERE (SubrecipientIDSheet.ID) = [Forms]![Subrecipient Information].[Form]![SubrepSubform].[Form]![ID];
```

Comment: If you want report filter to be same as subform filter, then why have dynamic parameter in report query? I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report.

Comment: I would like to be able to have both the form and report to utilize the split form view for the utility of the datasheet view to look at the results of the filtered form, and for the user to then be able to print a pre-formatted report if they would like to.

Comment: I seldom use split form but don't see how that changes my question/comment.